# error: initializer element is not constant - when linking to ROM symbols

Tags: c, gcc, linker, ld, rom

I am compiling with GCC for C code and received this error.

The intention is using overlay in linker script (these 2 sections below are overlayed) for bootloader to process the specific hardware version (hwver) before loading to that specific version of hardware.

```
const uint32_t _tableNum_U32_hwver1_ram = 12345;

extern const  uint32_t _tableNum_U32_hwver1_rom;  

__attribute__((section(".rodata.overlay.hwver1"))) 
const uint32_t tableNum_U32 =  _tableNum_U32_hwver1_rom;

__attribute__((section(".rodata.overlay.hwver2."))) 
const uint32_t tableNum_U32_hwver1 =  _tableNum_U32_hwver1_ram;  // this is in ram

void func(void)
{
...
      x = tableNum_U32 +6;  // example use
}
```

error: initializer element is not constant at line #4 above.

_tableNum_U32_hwver1_rom is located at ROM binary that is fed into linker using
flags:

```
-Wl --just-symbols="rom.sym"
```

How can I fix this error?

Please notice I cannot just use #define here, because it won't get compiled and built into the overlay.

Comment: replace second line with `#define tableNum_U32 _tableNum_U32`

Comment: `const` does not mean "constant". And names starting wiht underscore at file-level are reserved for the implementation. You must not use them in user-code.